# Nao consigo conectar no banco de dados MySql

Tags: mysql, asp, odbc, connectionstring

Eu possuo uma aplicação em ASP clássico e nao estou conseguindo fazer a conexão com o banco de dados. Configurei todos os paramentos certos

stringConexao = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3.9 ANSI Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=asseitsesi.com.br; UID=root; PWD=; Ignore Prepare=true; Connection Timeout=10; Option=3;"

Tem algum parâmetros errado na minha string de conexão?

Comment: Qual a mensagem de erro ?

Comment: Fala que não é possível conectar ao banco.

Comment: você sabe criar um udl para configurar e testar a conexão?

Comment: olá, na própria página que você tem a string de conexão coloque um response.write "ok" e rode a página para ver se está apresentando a mensagem "ok", se o problema for em uma página que chama a página de conexão como include e informar erro, veja se você habilitou o caminho Pai caso use IIS. Se possível para ajudar detalhe melhor seu problema.

Comment: Como você está tentando conectar o banco de dados de um domínio, lá você também precisa liberar a porta criando uma ODBC, veja no painel de controle do domínio que lá deve ter, crie igual você criou no PC.